# Python quit upon hitting the debug point, throw "called Tcl_FindHashEntry on deleted table" Error

Tags: python, pycharm

I am running my Python script using Pycharm on Mac.
The script is reading, processing and plotting some data.

When I place a debug point(often shortly after I plotted some charts), I encountered "python quit unexpectedly". My debugger logged:
"called Tcl_FindHashEntry on deleted table"

Would you please help? I want the program to stop at the debug point, instead of quitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error looks like its coming from the backend of MatPlotLib. Here is an [open bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7743) which references the same error. The bug may or may not be what you are experiencing, but has to do with window sizing and multiple screens.

As troubleshooting:

1. If multiple monitors or a dock are in use, try removing them from the equation.
2. Use Windows to examine breakpoint. (Bug appears Mac-specific.)